# Workflow engine compatibility

Tags: business-process-management

Workflow engines can execute business process descriptions made in BPEL,XPDL and others.

Considering that the two main descriptions languages used are BPEL (Business Process Execution Language) and BPMN2.0 (Business Process Modeling Notation) **I'd like to know if anyone has knowledge of a workflow engine that can execute both implementation**.

I'm asking this because although BPMN 2.0 has a mapping between the graphical notation and the execution part, it seems that it's not as well adopted as BPEL. On the other hand I didn't want just to end up with BPEL because of not having a graphical counterpart.

So workflow engine with BPMN 2.0 and BPEL and free...any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BPMN2.0 was released on January this year, it's impossible for a new standard like that to be as adopted as BPEL that was release more than 5 years ago. The good thing is that most of the vendors are implementing BPMN2.0 so the adoption looks pretty well for now. jBPM5 (www.jbpm.org) can execute BPMN2 models and provide a very extensible core to be extended and support BPEL, but once again, most of the vendors are focused on implementing BPMN2 these days.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I guess you are looking for suppliers with BPMN 2.0 Modeling, Exection and BPEL conformance. It should be on the OMG website if there are any, but not that I know of by heart.